# Как извлечь dbf файл из zip архива в readableStream в NODE JS

Tags: node.js, потоки-данных, zip, dbf

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть **ZIP** архив с несколькими файлами **DBF**.
Используя Node JS, необходимо извлечь их в readableStream(не записывая на диск) и обработать в парсере DBF.  Для парсинга dbf я использую пакет "**DBFStream**"

```
const dbfstream = require('dbfstream')
const fs = require('fs')

//------------------------------------------
// Extract pdf to readableStream
//------------------------------------------

// if source is already a readableStream, use it, otherwise treat as a filename
let dbf = dbfstream('readableStream', 'Windows-1251');

dbf.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```